# generate Token for OAuth (Twitter)

Tags: bash, cryptography

I am writing a simple bash script to download stream from Twitter:

```
curl -H "Authorization: ${TOKEN}" "$URL"
```

and I am looking for a way to generate the `$TOKEN`. I have all the input necessary (CONSUMER_KEY, ...), but where can I get the program `oauth_sign` that will generate the token from the input data?

```
TOKEN=$(oauth_sign $CONSUMER_KEY $CONSUMER_SECRET $ACCESS_TOKEN $ACCESS_SECRET GET $URL)
```

Comment: http://acme.com/software/oauth_sign/

Comment: If you want a more elaborate example there is this: http://www.bentasker.co.uk/documentation/20-developmentprogramming/23-howto-tweet-from-bash-scripts-using-oauth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just downloaded the link @goldilocks provided, http://acme.com/software/oauth_sign/, and confirmed that it compiles. Looks very straightfoward.

#### compile

```
$ make
gcc -c -Wall -O liboauthsign.c
liboauthsign.c: In function ‘oauth_sign’:
liboauthsign.c:123:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getpid’
liboauthsign.c:305:5: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 4 of ‘HMAC’ differ in signedness
/usr/include/openssl/hmac.h:99:16: note: expected ‘const unsigned char *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
rm -f liboauthsign.a
ar rc liboauthsign.a liboauthsign.o
ranlib liboauthsign.a
gcc -Wall -O oauth_sign.c -L. -loauthsign -lcrypto -o oauth_sign
```

#### usage

```
$ ./oauth_sign --help
usage:  oauth_sign [-q] consumer_key consumer_key_secret token token_secret method url [name=value ...]
```

*excerpt from README*

> To use it, you supply the four cryptographic cookies and the method
>   and URL of the request.  If it's a POST request with extra parameters,
>   you have to give those too.  Oauth_sign puts all this together and
>   makes the signature string.  The signature is generated using
>   HMAC-SHA1 as specified in RFC section 3.4.2, and is returned as an
>   Authorization header value as specified in RFC section 3.5.1.  This
>   header can then be used in an HTTP request via, for example, the
>   -h flag in http_get(1) and http_post(1) or the -H flag in curl(1).

Looks like it comes with a library exposing the fuctions for use in your own C applications as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Get a stream feed from a Twitter user](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/10449/get-a-stream-feed-from-a-twitter-user) uses bash commands to open a stream from Twitter. (from commandlinefu.com)

[image: commandlinefu.com capture]

[Step1 - Create the four oauth keys](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/10416/create-the-four-oauth-keys-required-for-a-twitter-stream-feed) required for a Twitter stream feed.

[Step2 - Create the signature base string](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/10417/create-the-signature-base-string-required-for-a-twitter-stream-feed) required for a Twitter stream feed.

[Step3 - Create the oauth token](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/10414/create-the-oauth-token-required-for-a-twitter-stream-feed) required for a Twitter stream feed.

[Step4 - Create the authorization header](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/10419/create-the-authorization-header-required-for-a-twitter-stream-feed) required for a Twitter stream feed.